# RegEx - Get All Characters After Last Slash in URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with a Google API that returns IDs in the below format, which I've saved as a string.  How can I write a Regular Expression in javascript to trim the string to only the characters after the last slash in the URL.

```
var id = 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/myemail%40gmail.com/base/nabb80191e23b7d9'
```

Answer (score 111):

Don't write a regex! This is trivial to do with string functions instead:

```
var final = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

It's even easier if you know that the final part will always be 16 characters:

```
var final = id.substring(id.length - 16);
```

Comment: Will not return anything is the url is `'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/myemail%40gmail.com/base/nabb80191e23b7d9/'`

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen Well, there isn't anything after the last slash there, of course.

Comment: I found this topic although I was looking for a PHP solution. I converted it, in case anyone is interested: `substr($id, strrpos($id, "/") + 1)`

Comment: Not an answer to the question!

Comment: @LinusGeffarth https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Why is this so upvoted? This shows up as the first question on google when searching for a regex solution. OP specifically asked for a regex, and the answer starts with "Don't write a regex" : (

Comment: @Mercury Cos it's sensible advice? "How do I knock a nail into a wall with a harpsichord?" "Don't: use a hammer."

Comment: substr is deprecated

Comment: @Dinesh It won't make a difference here and it'll never be removed from browsers, but yes, it is, and I've updated the code as you say.

Answer (score 56):

A slightly different regex approach:

```
var afterSlashChars = id.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1];
```

Breaking down this regex:

```
\/ match a slash
(  start of a captured group within the match
[^\/] match a non-slash character
+ match one of more of the non-slash characters
)  end of the captured group
\/? allow one optional / at the end of the string
$  match to the end of the string
```

The `[1]` then retrieves the first captured group within the match

Working snippet:

```js
var id = 'http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/myemail%40gmail.com/base/nabb80191e23b7d9';

var afterSlashChars = id.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1];

// display result
document.write(afterSlashChars);
```

Comment: Explanations make your answer much more valuable, than accepted one. Thanks!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev: Unfortunately, the explanation is wrong, and so is the answer.  Non-greedy quantifiers don't guarantee the shortest possible match, because they only affect where the match *ends*, not where it begins.  This regex matches from the *first* slash to the end.

Comment: @Alan Moore I don't know why I picked this answer, probably because it fitted me at the moment. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @AlanMoore - I modified the answer and added a working snippet.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev - I modified the answer and added a working snippet.

Comment: Okay, now it *is* the best answer. :D

Comment: @jfriend00 great answer and awesome explanation around your RegEx!

Answer (score 31):

Just in case someone else comes across this thread and is looking for a simple JS solution:

id.split('/').pop(-1)

Comment: Easy, short and nice. But the -1 argument seems redundant, as pop() always returns the last element.

Comment: This is genius! And elegant

Comment: Regexp seems to be faster https://jsperf.com/last-element-of-array-xxx/2

Answer (score 28):

this is easy to understand `(?!.*/).+`

let me explain:

first, lets match everything that has a slash at the end, ok? 
**that's the part we don't want**

`.*/` matches everything until the last slash

then, we make a "Negative lookahead" `(?!)` to say "I don't want this, discard it"

`(?!.*)` this is "Negative lookahead"

Now we can happily take whatever is **next to what we don't want** with this
`.+`

**YOU MAY NEED TO ESCAPE THE / SO IT BECOMES:**

`(?!.*\/).+`

Answer (score 13):

this regexp: `[^\/]+$` - works like a champ:

```
var id = ".../base/nabb80191e23b7d9"

result = id.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];

// results -> "nabb80191e23b7d9"
```

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
last = id.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1];
//=> nabb80191e23b7d9
```

Comment: Good answer. In Perl, regex delimeters must be escaped, even in character classes, otherwise it wouldn't find the regex to be parsed.

Answer (score 7):

Don't know JS, using others examples (and a guess)  -

`id = id.match(/[^\/]*$/);` // [0] optional ?

Comment: Just for the record, the match function returns an array.Using [0] is going to return just the first one. It's not optional.

Comment: There are no capture groups in this regex, isn't match overloaded to return the whole match if no index is referenced?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use replace?

```
"http://google.com/aaa".replace(/(.*\/)*/,"")
```

yields "aaa"