# How to get number after last slash using regex?

Tags: regex

For a URL such as this:

```
http://www.walmart.com/ip/0982724/some-text-here/234397280?foo=bar
```

How can I get a variable length number after the last slash?

I tried using this regex:

```
\/([0-9]+)
```

But it gets the first number, not the last one.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/nU3wG2

I tried adding a dollar sign at the end, but then there were no matches.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19776979

Comment: @RobertHarvey That gets all characters after the last slash, not just the number.

Comment: Yes, I know.  You probably should be using a Split function anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
\/([0-9]+)(?=[^\/]*$)
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eL3mK3

This means find a number which is followed by 0 or more non-slash string till end.

Comment: Why not just `\/([0-9]+)\?` or `\/([0-9]+)[^\/]*$`?

Comment: You can do that but then you need to get back reference to matched group # 1

Comment: Your answer also has a capture group.

Comment: the goal is last numbers, the look ahead is not needed.  \d instead of [0-9] and @emment the capture is needed.

Comment: Same regex can be written in more than one way isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without a rarely implemented lookahead feature if you can work with contents of capturing groups.

```
\/([0-9]+)[^\/]*$
```

**Online demo:** http://regex101.com/r/yG2zN1

This means "find a slash followed with any positive number of digits followed with any non-slash characters followed with end of the line". As regexps find the [longest leftmost](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Leftmost-Longest.html) match, all of those digits are captured into a group.

Answer (score 0):

```
$aa = "http://www.walmart.com/ip/0982724/some-text-here/234397280?foo=bar";

$aa =~ /\/(\d+)\D+$/;

print $1, "\n";
```

This prints 234397280 \D is any non digit \d is any digit it is the same as '[0-9]

Comment: Anyone remember the tv show, name that tune? I can name that song in three notes etc... I can do that regular expression in 10 characters :)