# Parsing the last substring of the url

Tags: php, regex

I want to parse the string after the last "/" .
For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1/~dtm/index.php/en/parts/engine
```

Parse the "engine" .

I tried do it with Regexp but as im new to regexp im stuck near the solution.
Also this pattern seems quite easy breakable (/engine/ will break it ) . Need somehow make it a bit more stable.

```
$pattern = ' \/(.+^[^\/]?) ' ;
```

- / Match the / char
- .+ Match any char one or more times
- ^[^/\ Exclude \ char

[Demo of the current state](https://regex101.com/r/rA3rM4/1)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776979/regex-get-all-characters-after-last-slash-in-url

Comment: **1** You have some spaces in your regex that probably shouldn't be there. **2** `^` (outside of a class) means beginning of string so it makes no sense to have it in the middle of a regex like that. **3** `.+[^\/]?` means some characters of any kind (`/` included) followed by an optional single character that is not `/` (so the whole thing can be shortened to `.+`). Perhaps a regex tutorial would be a good start.

Comment: `basename` is probably your best bet. `explode` + `end` or `array_pop`. `parse_url` might be useful, too. Really no need for regex _at all_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a regex, don't make it complicated just use this:

```
<?php

    $url = "http://127.0.0.1/~dtm/index.php/en/parts/engine";
    echo basename($url);

?>
```

Output:

```
engine
```

Comment: I searched for any premade functions that could do that, but dunno why i didnt find something about basename. Thanks dude ! This is sure way easier, better than regexp.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use performatner functions instead of preg_match to do this

eg basename()

```
   $url = "http://127.0.0.1/~dtm/index.php/en/parts/engine";
   echo basename($url);
```

or explode()

```
  $parts = explode('/',$url);
  echo array_pop($parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) together to achieve your goal.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1/~dtm/index.php/en/parts/engine';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$path = $parsed['path'];
echo array_pop(explode('/', $path));
?>
```

#### [PhpFiddle Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/3f0c7a7ccae4635b1efb)

Answer (score 0):

Is this something?

```
$url = "http://127.0.0.1/~dtm/index.php/en/parts/engine";
$ending = end(explode('/', $url));
```

Output:

```
engine
```