# JavaScript-How To Separate Path from File Name

Tags: javascript

I need to separate the file path from the file name: (some codes did not work in the past)
If the path is **www.example.com/hi/test/home.html**
How would I get just **www.example.com/hi/test/**?

Comment: Have a look at `split`, `pop` and `join` methods, then try something.

Comment: You can check this thread for details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776979/regex-get-all-characters-after-last-slash-in-url

Comment: `"www.example.com/hi/test/home.html".substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);`

Comment: I just did `var fullPath = path + "/";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `substring` and `lastIndexOf`:

```
a = "www.example.com/hi/test/home.html";
b = a.substr(0, a.lastIndexOf('/'));

// b = www.example.com/hi/test
```

Comment: Don't forget your `var`s, `const`s, or `let`s before your variables. : )

Comment: to get trailing slash `url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);`