# Get a one word query string value (JS or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Hello I would like to get the value of a one word query string and store that string into a variable.

For example if a user goes to:

`www.mysite.com/example`

I need some JS or jQuery to take the string `example` and store it into a variable for use in another function.

Ive done some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) question here, but these answers are more indepth, splitting the query string by &'s and stuff.

I just need to capture the value of one single word.

Thanks!

Comment: Please note in `www.mysite.com/example` there's no query string: `example` is the path.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax. So what do you really need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this fairly quickly:

```
//var url = (document.URL);
var url = ('http://www.example.com/example');
var index = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3rw93zv/) to play with.

The code above uses `document.URL` to get the full URL of the current document.

Then `substr` starting at one more than the last index of `/`. This will leave you with everything after the last `/`.

However, if your URL looked like "http://www.example.com/example/" this would return nothing, an empty string. You'd have to do some additional work to account for that. This is why some examples would use `.split()` since you can then split the URL at every `/` and grab the item from an array.

In the spirit of providing not just an answer but the right one, I think a **regular expression** and `.match()` is the right way to go. [This solution comes from a very similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776979/regex-get-all-characters-after-last-slash-in-url).

```
var url = ('http://www.example.com/example/test/example2/');
var index = url.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1];
```

This will give you `example2` regardless of a whether or not a trailing slash exists.

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3rw93zv/3/).

Comment: awesome this is exactly what I was looking for. thanks!