# Regex get file path of firebase from its link

Tags: regex

I want to get the file path by its firebase link. For example, the source url was
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dev.appspot.com/o/temp%2F1-5%2Ftemp_file_637605453170534484%2F2.png?alt=media&token=575e6226-1ffc-4697-b44a-724d2b7f734d"

I want to only get the `temp%2F1-5%2Ftemp_file_637605453170534484%2F2.png` (this part changes every time, it was not always a .png or temp at start) part. I know its possible with regex but I'm not familiar with regex and I cant find a key to compare. Note that the firebase url seems like to be constants on the start string so every url I have its start with `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dev.appspot.com/o/`

Comment: You question lacks details: 1. Does the desired substring always start with `temp`? 2. Does it always end with `.png` or `?`, etc.

Comment: @frankenapps it wont since the file thats the file name and they allowed to upload any files

Comment: Please show your attempted regex

Comment: **Assuming** that the string you want is always at the end of the url (after the last `/`, i.e. it doesn't have any slashes in it) then it becomes quite easy. Try `[^\/]+$` this regex, which basically says _"match all (1 or more) non-slash characters at the end of the string"_ . Or just split it at all slashes and take the last part (that doesn't even use regex)

Comment: Edit : I found this existing SO post with answers to do what I suggested, if that works for you... It even has the same regex pattern i just commented, with other possibilities https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776979/regex-get-all-characters-after-last-slash-in-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to group the base URL, File path, and the query parameters like this.

```
(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dev.appspot.com/o/)(.*)(\?.*)
```

Then you will get the complete URL as the full match and,

`Capturing group 1` : `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dev.appspot.com/o/`

`Capturing group 2` : `temp%2F1-5%2Ftemp_file_637605453170534484%2F2.png`

`Capturing group 3` : `?alt=media&token=575e6226-1ffc-4697-b44a-724d2b7f734d`

You can get the complete file path by extracting `capturing group 2`